# Integer changes value without changing it in for loop

Tags: c++

[This kind of explains it all](https://photos.app.goo.gl/6DHpTZsoULZfmYAc8) I really don't know why this is happening, can you guys help? I even made the length constant because I though that could be the problem, but it still happens so I really don't know.
So the problem is that I define length1 as 4, but then after a few times in the for loop, the value just randomly changes...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int uppercase[26] = {65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90};
int lowercase[26] = {97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122};
string test;
int entered_text[] = {};
int length = 0;
int length1 = 0;

int main() {
    cout << "Enter Text:" << endl;
    getline (cin, test);
    length = test.size();
    length1 = 4;
    cout << test<< endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < length1; i++){
        entered_text[i] = test[i];
    }
    cout << entered_text[0] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Post your code as text in SO

Comment: @Tarik yeah I realized I forgot to do that after posting

Comment: Please add your explanation here... instead of linking to a video

Comment: @Tarik Okay, I did that

Comment: @YoupLamb I think your problem is that you have allocated zero memory for your fixed-size array (`entered_text`) and in the loop you are going over the boundaries of that array and changing the following memory (`length` and `length1` probably) instead of the array. You should either use `std::vector` for you character input, or allocate some amount of bytes that would be enough for your input (say `int entered_text[256] = {};`.

Comment: @Mat The exercise is that I need to make uppercase text lowercase, by using ASCII values so it just needs to store a few letters

Comment: Having a lookup table `uppercase` or `lowercase` seems over complicated to me, instead of just subtracting 65 or 97 resp.

Comment: @Mat I did not use std::vector because I have absolutely no idea what that is :D, I am a huge noob

Comment: @YoupLamb If you, as a beginner, have no idea what `std::vector` is and try to _somehow_ work with pointers and arrays you are using a bad learning resource. In modern C++ you almost never have to or should use plain arrays or raw pointers.

Comment: Since they're not used in this code, it's not clear what the role of `uppercase` and `lowercase` is. But chances are that they're duplicating standard library functionality. Don't roll your own, and don't hard-code ASCII values. Use the standard library functions `isupper`, `islower`, `toupper` and `tolower`.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your code, it seems you're approaching this problem as if you were coding in JavaScript and using objects.  Obviously, C++ does not approach objects the same way as JavaScript (nowhere near the same).

Here is a rough example of what you could do instead.  I don't understand what you're trying to do, but I believe you can implement dynamic arrays and pointers to tackle the problem you have.  Read up on using C++ pointers and C++ dynamic arrays.  Here is some "rough" code that will hopefully get you on your way:

```
int main() {
    cout << "Enter Text:" << endl;
    getline (cin, test);
    cout << test<< endl;

    length = test.size();

//  Create dynamic array and have this array the size of your string. 
//  Also, initialize a pointer to point to the address of your new array
    int *enteredText;
    enteredText = new char [length]; 
    int *save = enteredText;

// Iterate over the array “entered_text” and assign it values
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        *entered_text = test[i];
        entered_text++;
    }

//  now print chars
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        cout << *save << endl;
        save++;
    }
    return 0;
```

Comment: It doesn't matter how you intialize an array. The usage is always the same.

Comment: Get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than assigning initial values later. In this case that means changing `int *enteredText; enteredText = new char [length];` to `int *enteredText = new char[length];`. And don't forget to delete the array when you're done. Further, you don't need that two-step with `save` and `entered_text++`; you can index into the array with `entered_text[i]` or, even better, just use `std::copy`.

Answer (score 0):

don't make every variable you use global, its better to keep them local if there's no strong reason to do otherwise, and in c++ you have to tell your compiler the size of your array, or use allocation, but I would suggest to use `std::vector<int>`